# mysql query order by listings that have been paid for

Tags: mysql

i'm having a bit of trouble trying to write an sql query. i have a table for `listings`, now all i am trying to do here is make it so that listings that have been paid for will show up at the top of the results.

so say i am on province page and the province ID is 23, i need to make the listings that have `upgrade_province`='yes' and `upgrade_status`='paid' and `id_province`='23' show up as the first results ordered by date, and everything else below those ordered by date. if `upgrade_province`='yes' and `upgrade_status`='unpaid' then it needs to show that listing as a normal listing.

heres the table structure:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`contact_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`title_slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`id_province` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_city` int(11) NOT NULL,
`map_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_contract` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bedrooms` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`bathrooms` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image_main` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image_4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image_5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Active',
`upgrade_urgent` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'no',
`upgrade_city` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'no',
`upgrade_province` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'no',
`upgrade_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`upgrade_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'unpaid',
`num_views` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`num_replies` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`date_posted` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_upgrade` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`mod_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'approved',
```

i can't seem to figure out how i can make it treat unpaid ads as normal even if their `upgrade_province`='yes'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arbitrary expressions in ORDER BY clauses. The boolean true/false values will get treated as '0' and '1' integers which can be ordered with ASC/DESC as usual, so

```
...rest of query...
ORDER BY (upgrade_province='yes' and upgrade_status='paid' and id_province='23') DESC,
   ... other order clauses ...
```

Any records which evaluate to TRUE in that 'and' sequence will evaluate to a '1', which when ordered DESC will appear first in the results. Anything which comes out false is cast to 0 and will sort lower.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding his desired result, the answer Marc B offered is not appropriate.  Specifying multiple order by clauses causes secondary sorts on collisions of the first and so on.

My understanding of the question is there are two distinct sets of things that need to be sorted differently.

Also the order by clause is incorrect.  He wants that to be part of the where clause and then ordered by date after the set is identified.

I would suggest trying

```
select .. from table where (upgrade_province='yes' and upgrade_status='paid' and id_province='23') order by date desc
union
select .. from table where (upgrade_province!='yes' and upgrade_status!='paid' and id_province!='23') order by date desc
```

Note: the way you negate the second part of the union might need the ands changed to ors depending on what exactly you want.

Either way to point is to independently select the two different sets and sort them with in themselves.  Something similar could also be accomplished on the application level issuing multiple queries and having the app sort it out as desired.